# Clojure - call one method from another, both methods are in the same protocol/record

Tags: clojure

A protocol has two methods:

```
(defprotocol ITimeInterop
  (parse-int [this str])
  (stringify-time [this host-time]))
```

Here I am calling `parse-int` from `stringify-time`:

```
(defrecord CljTime []
  ITimeInterop
  (parse-int [_ str]
    (Integer. (re-find #"[0-9]*" str)))
  (stringify-time [the-obj host-time]
    (let [specific-format (SimpleDateFormat. "MM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss")
          as-str (.format specific-format host-time)
          [month day-of-month year time-str] (str/split as-str #" ")
          month-as-idx (dec (parse-int the-obj month))]
      {})))
```

The error message I am getting is 'java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: parse-int in this context'.

How should I be calling `parse-int` from `stringify-time`?

Perhaps using a dot in front of parse-int would help?

**Answer** Unfortunately I did not show namespaces in the question. Using a dot seemed to work but a better resolution was to `:require` the protocol's namespace `:as` `i` then call using: `(i/parse-int the-obj month)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no problem calling `parse-int` in `stringify-time` as long as you provide with the `this` as the first argument, which is exactly what you have done. But in your presented code, I expect the error message to be "unable to resolve `month`".

I'd suggest you double check your question first.

Comment: Good point - my mistake - I've bolstered the let form now. To my understanding the call should be (using non-lisp pseudo-code): `the-obj.parse-int( month)`, and the signature of `parse-int` looks correct for that.

Comment: @ChrisMurphy Again, I was unable to reproduce your error. After `(import 'java.text.SimpleDateFormat)` and `(require '[clojure.string as str])`, I can run your code snippet with no problem. The problem must be lying somewhere else. Try get a minimal case and run it with a clean REPL.

Comment: A bit to add. The functions defined in `defprotocol` are merely plain old functions. So, after their declaration, they can be reference within the same namespace.

Comment: I got past that particular error message by using a dot. Now another error. I just did a push with the current error message - CljTime does not exit: https://github.com/chrismurrph/graphing/tree/points-not-paint/src/graphing

Comment: Just had a peek at your code. 1) Your `defprotocol` is defined in a different namespace as the `defrecord`, and the latter had not referred the method `parse-int`, therefore rendering the first error. 2) CljTime is a `defrecord`, it should not be `require`-ed and `refer`-ed, but `import`ed.

Comment: Got past those with [this commit](https://github.com/chrismurrph/graphing/tree/c60e931a4b4171facb5fcb931fcd541de8af1446/src/graphing) (permalink), but still have `ClassNotFoundException` for the import of the `CljTime` record.

Comment: Finally got past `ClassNotFoundException`. Apparently you don't have to import records but can `:require`. This worked: `(:require [graphing.clj-interop :as ci])` then `(def abst-time (ci/->CljTime))`.